# No Wifi adapter found?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, iwlwifi

I'm using ubuntu 18.4. My system froze and did a reboot, since then my wifi is not working. I tried the solution suggested in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416180/ubuntu-no-wifi-adapter-found) but to no avail. I have dual boot with windows and it's not working in windows either. Here is the output `sudo lshw -class network`

```
  *-network DISABLED        
   description: Wireless interface
   product: WiFi Link 5100
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: wlp1s0
   version: 00
   serial: 00:26:c6:32:f9:0e
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-43-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:29 memory:d5600000-d5601fff


  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: enp4s0
   version: 02
   serial: 00:26:9e:ab:16:9f
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:17 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:d2410000-d2410fff memory:d2400000-d240ffff memory:d3600000-d360ffff


  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: enp0s29f7u2
   serial: 0a:35:86:97:9f:c0
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.234 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a hardware issue (board not working) and not a Unix/Linux issue

Answer (score 2):

From the output of lsshw, where it says network DISABLED and from the telltale of Windows not working, it seems obvious it is hardware related.

You pressed the hardware switch/button to disable the WiFi adapter service by mistake. Press the switch again. WiFi should come up on its own, if not, reboot afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Allright guys, This was a hardware issue. Wifi card was not working. Sorry.