# Ubuntu WiFi network adaptor not found

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, dpkg

I know this question has been asked a couple of times however none of the answers seem to solve my issue. The problem is that the solutions provided somehow require internet connection before I can be able to run the command (i.e, the supposed solution) below and reboot;

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

- I have tried USB tethering with both WiFi and phone but it just doesn't work. I know it should because I've used it a couple of times but unfortunately it does not :(
- I have also tried to update and install additional drivers from the Ubuntu **software and updates** program by using an ISO image stored in my home directory. It still doesn't work
- Finally, I tried to manually download the package from the Ubuntu packages website then copy to my computer and install, this was also futile. [**NOT RECOMMENDED**]

Is there any other method available that may not require internet connection? really desperate...

Here is a link to a similar question: [Ubuntu | No WiFi Adapter found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416180)

Comment: can you paste the result of the command `sudo lspci | grep Network`

Comment: yes, I saw this useful check online while troubleshooting earlier on. Unfortunately, I didn't save my output. Thanks, all the same

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a fix for this.

- I happened to have multiple versions of the kernel boot image in the **/boot** directory so I removed the current one and used a lower version to boot, then made necessary install and updates.

I think I was the cause of the problem because I remember randomly selecting lighter software packages to install when the **software updater** program popped up during my last session and somehow something broke. I was only trying to conserve data spent on installs :)